# Use SCNNode as render "mask"?

Tags: ios, swift, shader, scenekit

Is it possible to cause a node to render "clear" such that when in is drawn, any views underneath the scene view are shown where the node would normally be shown?

For example, assume that our SCNView has a red UIView behind it. Using a sphere as an example, you would see a circular "hole" in the scene view where the the red view would show through.

Any ideas? Would this involve a shader of some sort?

Comment: If you've found answer to this question, you can add answer here. This will help other users.

Answer (score 0):

#### The Cut-out Effect

Let's assume that you placed a red-color UIView under the SCNView with a default `ship.scn` scene. To implement the cut-out effect based on SCNNode's alpha channel and redView's `.mask` instance property, use the following code:

```
import SceneKit

class ViewController : UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: SCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let redView: UIView = self.view {
            redView.mask = self.sceneView
        }
        if let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn") {
            self.sceneView.scene = scene
        }
        self.sceneView.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.sceneView.scene?.lightingEnvironment.contents = .none
        self.sceneView.scene?.background.contents = .none
    }
}
```

[image]